# horizontally align 2 elements in a layout android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to center horizontally the ratingbar and the textview inside the linearlayout.
The thing is like ratingbar is smaller than the textview, I don't get a correct aligment.
How should I do???

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/author_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/author_name"
    >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
        style="@style/SmallRatingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="5"

        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_text"
        android:rating="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_text"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Use gravity as center

Answer (score 0):

Try This...Change... on RatingBar change layout_width to match_parent

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ll1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"

android:layout_below="@id/author_name"
>

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
    style="@style/SmallRatingBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_text"
    android:rating="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_text"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:textSize="18sp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: It's not working. The stars will take all the width of the parent, and the textView is not visible anymore! Tx anywaY!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion and as google suggests, its not a good idea to use linearlayout in relative layout, you can implement it using just relative layout like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/author_name"
    android:text="d"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/texto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/author_name" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/texto"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/texto"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/rtbProductRating"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:text="asdf"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

unfortunately I dont understand what you mean by stating RatingBar is smaller than textview! and how would it like to be when centering them?

Comment: The height of each component is different, and they align with the bottom line. I would like them to align midlle line.

Answer (score 0):

See the below code, I have modified it a bit so that I can test it on my side. Its working fine. You can use this code. Please modify accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/author_name"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:isIndicator="true"
            android:numStars="5"
            android:rating="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The same aligment is happening. The height of each component is different, and they align with the bottom line. I would like them to align midlle line. Tx

Answer (score 0):

by using linear layout 
you can use 
android:gravity="center"

the following layout can do what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/author_name"
    android:text="d"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/author_name"
    >

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rtbProductRating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:rating="0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="sdf"
        android:textSize="18sp" >

]
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```